# Debugging - Improperly nested PHP if statement

Tags: php, debugging, if-statement

I have a moderately complex PHP if statement with a few levels.  Took me a while to get to this point but I just discovered that `if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') {}` echoes true outside of the following code so I know I have a syntax error.  Here is the code

In the following code, I know that my problem is on the commented lines:

```
        <?php

        $post_id = get_the_ID();

        if (in_category( array('blog','blog-fr'))) {
                echo '<h4 class="post_date"><span class="smaller">Posted On </span> ';
                the_time('F j, Y');
                echo '</h4>';
        } elseif (in_category( array('events','evenements','featured','en-vedette','performances','performances-evenements','productions','productions-evenements','workshops','ateliers','world-citizen-dance','world-citizen-dance-evenements'))) {
                echo '<h4 class="event_top_date"><span class="month">';
                    //either it's THIS line
                    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') { event_s_fr_month(); }
                    //or THIS one
                    else { if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M')));}
                echo '</span><span class="day">';
                if( function_exists (event_date('start','d')));         
                echo '</h4>';
        } else {
                echo '<h4 class="post_date"><span class="smaller">Posted On </span> ';
                the_time('F j, Y');
                echo '</h4>';
        } ?>
```

**EDIT: Code below has been updated from the comments, but still not working**

```
        } elseif (in_category( array('events','evenements','featured','en-vedette','performances','performances-evenements','productions','productions-evenements','workshops','ateliers','world-citizen-dance','world-citizen-dance-evenements'))) {
                echo '<h4 class="event_top_date"><span class="month">';
                    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr') { event_s_fr_month();}
                    else { event_date('start','M');}
                echo '</span><span class="day">';
                if( function_exists (event_date('start','d')));         
                echo '</h4>';
```

Comment: your **the only** problem is awfully bad code formatting. as soon you make it readable, you will see an error clearly

Comment: What IDE are you using? I know that in Notepad++, there is a setting that has brace/bracket/parenthesis matching & highlighting.

Comment: Just to clarify this, I have verified that the string `else { if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M')));}` behaves as I'm expecting it to, if I drop the if (ICL...) then it returns true.  The problem is that `event_s_fr_month();` is returning false on French pages and true on English.

Comment: Its not behaving how you are expecting it to, its just echoing a value, inside of a function, inside of a conditional that is doing nothing, which may somehow still be echoing your value and preventing a fatal. Also, nothing should be 'echoing true' or 'echoing false', they should be echoing a value or not.  In addition, one function will execute within an if/else block.  Honestly, its a complete disaster

Comment: Yup, I know you're right... Yes, they are echoing a value on the English side and nothing on the French side.  I just can't figure out why the different behavior on different ICL settings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php

function_exists() takes a string parameter to determine whether a function of that name exists or not.

lets say `event_date('start', 'd')` returns a string "fri" or something

with this: `if( function_exists (event_date('start','d')));`

you are saying: if there is a function named 'fri()', do nothing

It looks like you're using Wordpress, and the event_date function I'm guessing is not being echoed.  Also, you should be able to assume the function exists.

try something like this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$categories = array('events','evenements','featured','en-vedette','performances','performances-evenements','productions','productions-evenements','workshops','ateliers','world-citizen-dance','world-citizen-dance-evenements');
if( in_category( array('blog','blog-fr') ) )
{
    echo '<h4 class="post_date"><span class="smaller">Posted On </span> ';
    the_time('F j, Y');
    echo '</h4>';
}
elseif (in_category( $categories ) )
{
    echo '<h4 class="event_top_date"><span class="month">';
    if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr')
    {
        echo event_s_fr_month();
    }
    else
    {
        echo event_date( 'start','M' );
    }
    echo '</span><span class="day">';
    event_date('start','d');
    echo '</h4>';
}
else
{
    echo '<h4 class="post_date"><span class="smaller">Posted On </span> ';
    the_time('F j, Y');
    echo '</h4>';
}
```

If by some chance you do need those functions available though, wrap them like this:

```
if( function_exists( 'event_date' ) )
{
    echo event_date( 'start','M' );
}
```

Comment: Believe it or not, my problem is even bigger than this.  For some reason s_fr_month(); echoes true on the English pages but NOT on the French pages, LOL.  What's crazy is that the function works and it's not an improper nesting issue because replacing `event_s_fr_month();` with `the_date();` results in the date echoing true.  So, the problem is somehow a conflict between one of the many modules / plugins the site is running.  Thanks for your help though!  :(

Comment: Again, apologies that this is not something that can really be debugged without actually working on the server live.  It seems that there's some extremely buggy conflict between modules, the `event_s_fr_month();` function is returning false on French pages (including outside of my posted code) and true on English pages.

Comment: Your function or plugin with this function isn't getting loaded on your french pages, which is probably why its not returning a value.  You need to supply more data about which plugin you are using, and how you are displaying french vs english pages before anyone can really determine the root of your problem. Are you getting fatals?  Blank screens?  Have you looked at your error log?  Have errors/warnings turned on?

Comment: This is a good point Brandon.  I think that's what I needed to know.  Sorry that I'm only discovering this after you and others have spent time trying to help :(

Comment: Also, the most unusual part is that the `event_date()` function is returning true and it's contained in the SAME PHP INCLUDE that the `event_s_fr_month();` function is contained in.  And BOTH work on the English page, but only `event_date()` returns true on the French page.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this semicolon

```
 else { if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M')));  <-- This semicolon }
```

And where is the true part of this if statement put some code which will be executed if there is the passed function exists.

```
 else { if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M'))) {  //True part code here }  }
```

Probably you need `if..elseif`

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'fr')
{ 
    event_s_fr_month(); 
}
else if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M')))
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: I agreed when I saw your answer, but unfortunately that's not it.  I have that same line elsewhere in the code and it works there.  Also, FYI - I did test it out to verify, but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure that `else { if ( function_exists (event_date('start','M')));}` is incorrect. You probably want something like `elseif ( function_exists (event_date('start','M'))){ // code here }`. Where `// code here` is whatever action you'd like to take if that statement is true.

Comment: I agreed when I saw your answer, but unfortunately that's not it.  I have that same line elsewhere in the code and it works there.  Also, FYI - I did test it out to verify, but that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

What does [netbeans](http://netbeans.org) say?

Using a php editor that highlights syntax errors make these kinds of errors easy to debug.

Or use "Source -> Format" to reformat to see how the code is nested.

PS.

```
 if( function_exists (event_date('start','d'))
```

Executes the event_date() function and checks if the returnvalue is a existing function.

I haven't seen this construction before, did you mean:

```
 if ( function_exists('event_date') ) {
   event_date('start','d')
 }
```